# Have multiple colours in one textItem - Photoshop API

Tags: javascript, adobe

I have a textItem inside my photoshop file which I would like to have specific letters certain colours. For example first two letters red, next three yellow, next 2 green etc...

I am able to change the overall text colour of the item `nameLayer.textItem.characterStyle.color = ....;` but would like to change these individually.

I have thought about trying these in various text boxes, but in some cases these strings can go on for 100+ characters. Would greatly appreciate any advice.

My full code for this TextItem.

```
var nameLayer = layers.getByName("Bat_1_Name");
nameLayer.textItem.contents = batsman.name;
nameLayer.textItem.characterStyle.size = 45;

//Change the colour of the entire block
nameLayer.textItem.characterStyle.color = ....;
```